# How to restrict file type (e.g. .pdf) in HTML5?

Tags: html, html-input

How to restrict file type (e.g. .pem, .cer) using in HTML5. The accept tag does not serve the purpose fully, as I can type some other file type and the file gets uploaded. The field is of input type "file".

Comment: this has nothing to do with thymeleaf. thymeleaf is templating engine. it is only responsible for generating HTML

Comment: what do you mean by "type some other file type"?

Answer (score 1):

For example all audio types:

```
<input type=file accept="audio/*">
```

1 audio type:

```
<input type=file accept="audio/mp3">
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 does not provide a way to exempt specific file types.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q. How to restrict file type in HTML5?**

This is not possible in a fool-proof way.

> **Q. Why?**

1. The `accept` attribute on the `input` tag is only a helper attribute. It is not a validation tool (see the tip on [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) that clarifies this).  Therefore, expecting the `accept` attribute to validate the files is unrealistic.
2. Support for the `accept` attribute varies across web browsers (even their latest versions) so another reason not to depend on this attribute for validating files being uploaded.
3. There is no other mechanism in HTML5 to validate file uploads.
4. Even if the client (web browser) could enforce file extensions, users can always rename files to an acceptable format and upload them.  For example, if HTML could restrict upload to PDF files, nothing stops the users from renaming EXE files to PDF and uploading them.

> **Q. So what's the solution?**

Always validate data on the server-side.  Uploads are no different than other types of data.  Even if there are safeguards on the client to validate data, it must always be validated on the server side.  Use the client-side options as helpers but don't overly rely on them.